# rails generate devise User error when migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm a bit new in Rails world and I try to add a new field in devise schema.

I found this :

```
rails generate model NAME [field[:type][:index] field[:type]
```

and tried to apply the command :

```
rails generate devise User linkedin:string
```

The process seemed correct :

```
invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20130902085306_add_devise_to_users.rb
  insert    app/models/user.rb
   route  devise_for :users
```

But when I launch a db:migrate it occures an error :

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
```

What did I do wrong ? why does it say (and is it related) email is wrong while it was ok before ?

Thanks a lot !

---

Here is the migration file result :

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
change_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at

  ## Token authenticatable
  # t.string :authentication_token

  t.string :linkedin

  # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
  # t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
# add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
end

def self.down
# By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
# model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your users table already have email field? It seems there is, you have to remove creating an email field again by removing it from migration and make sure it is not referenced twice in user.rb model

```
db/migrate/20130902085306_add_devise_to_users.rb
```

Comment: true ! the migration file begins with this :   change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""           But why the new linkedin field is not defined here ?

Comment: LinkedIn field? I am not sure it includes it? but it looks like you have commented the authenticable field

Comment: Ok, looking forward in the code, there is a t.string:linkedin declaration, but the migration file seems to "create" all the table instead of updating it

Comment: Just post your migration here then. The one you have posted above is for updating users table only

Answer (score 0):

Ok! 
I've found what was wrong : I created a new table instead of updating existing one. 
So the good task was :

```
rails g migration add_columnLinkedin_to_users
```

Then adding in the new created migration file :

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.string   :linkedin
end
```

And db:migrate was a success !

Thanks for your helps !